# Copying from ext4 to ext4 partition really slow?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount, nautilus, ext4

So, I have a couple of ext4 partitions on my harddisk, and another time, I got a copying speed of 8-12 Mb/s, but now its around 1-2 Mb/s, and because I'd like to copy 70 GB, thats a way to slow.
Any help is greatly appreciated. I have a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.02 install, and I also tried mounting it manually using `mount /dev/sda4 /media/user/`.
Probably thats my fault ?

**EDIT**

note :

- Using Debian Jessie I got 30 Mb/s copying exactly the same files
- With another partition that I didnt mount manually I got 8-12 Mb/s
- It isnt on another harddisk, it's my builtin HDD with 500 GB capacity on which I have multiple ext4 partitions. On this HDD is also my Ubuntu .
- I dont think that the files are so small, but they're all different, many around 1MB, a lot of small txt files and programmes around 5-100 KB, and even some Ubuntu isos I downloaded..., but they're not so small, like for example containing one char and having a filename that is as long as possible...
- Output of smartctl -a /dev/sda4 :

Infos :

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Laptop Thin HDD
Device Model:     ST500LT012-1DG142
Serial Number:    W3PFMRFQ
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 08293eb8d
Firmware Version: 0002LVM1
User Capacity:    500.107.862.016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Mar 25 13:03:51 2017 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 101) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1031) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   118   099   034    Pre-fail  Always       -       183936888
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       3023
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   078   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       64977593
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       5283
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1844
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   064   054   045    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 22/37)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2489
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       522
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   059   059   000    Old_age   Always       -       82582
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   036   046   000    Old_age   Always       -       36 (0 15 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Is it just those specific files? Is there fluctuations? Is the HDD getting old? What changed between the 8-12/1-2 speeds?

Comment: How is this hard disk connected? Via USB 2? Have you checked the S.M.A.R.T. status of the drive (for example with 'Disks' or with `smartctl`? Could it be that there are extremely many very small files, which are located at scattered locations, so that there must be a lot of 'startup intervals' with mechanical motion, that takes time?

Comment: What is the sort of the content you are trying to copy? If you have to copy large number of small files slow speed is normal.

Comment: @SpasSpasov : Yes, there are around 400.000 files, but the speed of 8-12 Mb/s was also with a similar amount of files, but on another partition(also ext4), it had the 8/12  Mb/s speed, but I think this partition was mounted differently...

Comment: @Norr : There's quite a lot, so Ill edit.

Comment: @sudodus : Ill edit and give some morer infos.

Comment: @sudodus : Whats the smart state ?

Comment: 'SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED'. See details at http://www.hdsentinel.com/smart/index.php - Read and write within the same drive is slower than between different drives. Different drives have different speed for moving mechanical details as well as for processing the electronic signals. Maybe the configuration of the partitions and file systems are not optimal. Maybe there is some slow buffering of data with Ubuntu, and Debian Jessie works better. I suggest that you use Debian to copy huge amounts of data, for example booted from a live drive.

Comment: @sudodus : I did even install it ! But the problem was, always when I installed/removed something, it removed and installed around 1000 packages. For example : sudo apt-get install netbeans. After that almost the whole GNOME was removed, including Libre Office.

Comment: @sudodus : Thanks for your help. Solution : Waiting around 12h.

Comment: You can use a live USB drive with Debian for fast copying, for example from the following link to an iso file, http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/ - I have used the lxde version (which I think is the 'lightest').